# can not create text files in a c program

Tags: c

I want to create 1000000 text files in a folder, by a c program, but it creates only 508 text files in a folder. My code is:

```
 int i, j;
 char temp[100];

 for(j=0;j<100;j++)
    temp[j]= NULL;

 for (i=0;i<1000000;i++)
 {
    sprintf(temp,"%ld.sift",i);
    fopen(temp,"w+");
 }
```

Comment: The code misses to close the files, so the system might run out of resources.

Comment: check `FOPEN_MAX <stdin.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Also call `fclose` after you've created the file - you can't have `1000000000000` files opened at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
int i, j;
char temp[100];
FILE *fp;

memset(temp , '\0' , 100 );

for (i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
   sprintf(temp,"%ld.sift",i);
   fp = fopen(temp,"w+");
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out by others the code seems to be missing to `fclose()` the file `fopen()`ed, so the system most probably runs out of resources keeping all those file open.

To fix this just close them, before creating new ones.

---

If on Linux and you just want to create the (empty) files without opening them the [`mknod()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html) function can be used for this.